# create a python exe for users without python - that can handle server CGI

Tags: python, localhost, cgi

I have written a simple python localhost server that contains a python CGI script. The CGI returns html based on a user search.

I would like to build a compiled version that creates a local host for users and lets them run the python CGI script (without installing python).

I've used pyinstaller to create an exe of the server program. However, when the CGI is called, it's still trying to run uncompiled python (which the user's machine won't have).

Any thoughts on how to make the CGI available to users without installing python?

Comment: Did you follow all of these steps http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial

Comment: I did try py2exe at first as well, but it isn't compatible with 3.5. So I switched to pyinstaller.

I also tried the trick of changing the name of the lib packages on 3.4 to 3.5 for py2exe, but it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work via these steps:

1. Use flask instead of a simple HTML server (CGIHTTPRequestHandler). This is huge overkill for serving static files, but it works. It required minimal refactoring since flask can take information similarly to CGI using: request.args.get
2. Compile using pyinstaller. This doesn't work at first but generates a [your app].spec file.
3. Doctored the spec file to include additional data per instructions on this page: https://www.quora.com/Can-I-convert-a-Flask-application-into-an-executable-file-that-runs-on-Windows-like-an-exe-file (Definitely some voodoo here, but it works!)
4. Added in additional directories that I needed (a search index) in the a.datas calls.
5. Reran the pyinstaller using the modified spec file instead of the .py file.

Code added in step 3 (it's a picture in the quora link)

```
         hiddenimports=['email','email.message',
            'email.mime.message', 'email.mime.image',
            'email.mime.text', 'email.mime.multipart',
                'email.mime.audio', 'email.mime.multipart',
           ],

def extra_datas(mydir):
     def rec_glob(p,files):
         import os
         import glob
         for d in glob.glob(p):
             if os.path.isfile(d):
                 files.append(d)
             rec_glob("%s/*" % d, files)
     files = []
     rec_glob("%s/*" % d, files)
     extra_datas = []
     for f in files: 
         extra_datas.append((f, f, 'DATA'))
     return extra_datas

#include our data directories
a.datas += extra_datas("static")
a.datas += extra_datas("templates")
```